# Permission Denied: File Creation in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

After compiling the following code in Eclipse using a Mac:

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class Filer{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        File f1;

        f1 = new File("/System/file.txt");

        if(!f1.exists()){
            f1.createNewFile();

        }
      }
    }
```

I get an error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
        at Filer.main(Filer.java:11)
```

Can anyone tell me why that is? Is there any way to change the permissions? And if I were to compile this as a .jar file and send it to someone, would that person have the correct permissions?

Comment: Not anyone can write anywhere on a filesystem. `/System` looks like OS X and it is owned by root, who is the only one who can write there. Maybe chose another directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why that is?

Your user doesn't have permission to create a file in that directory.

> Is there any way to change the permissions?

The same way you would change the permissions of any directory.

In Java 7+

```
Files.setPosixFilePermisions(f1.toPath(), 
    EnumSet.of(OWNER_READ, OWNER_WRITE, OWNER_EXECUTE, GROUP_READ, GROUP_EXECUTE));
```

> And if I were to compile this as a .jar file and send it to someone, would that person have the correct permissions?

I suspect the correct permissions for a directory called `/System` is that you NOT have write access.

Is there any reason not to use the home directory or the current working directory?

Comment: Alternatively, use `sudo java` to run the code (and accept that it won't work inside Eclipse). Not writing to `/System` at all is the better solution though!

Comment: Would sending it to the desktop be a better option? Is there a way to detect username of the current computer? i.e. /Users/**username**/Desktop/file.txt

Comment: You can use the user's home directory e.g. `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop"` See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: It would have been great to explain "the same way you would change the permissions of any directory"

Comment: If you don't have write permissions to the directory it is rather unlikely you will have enough permission to change that.

Comment: @EJP I was thinking that.  Most likely you have to ask the person who own the directory or sys admin to change the permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Only users with special privileges are allowed to write in the *System* directory.

Normal users can only write in their home directory