# How to write a file in java at a location which needs super user privileges?

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to write a file using java. I am using ubuntu platform. I am able to write it in home folder but it needs super user privileges to be written in /var/foo folder(which is obvious!). How to write a file with super user privileges so that I can write the file in /var/foo folder? Currently my code snippet and the exception are as follows:

```
public class WritetoFile
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File("/var/foo/abc.txt");

        if (!f.exists())
    {
        f.createNewFile();
    }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write("Hello world!");
        bw.close();
   }
}
```

when I execute it I get following exception(obviously!)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:959)
    at WritetoFile.main(WritetoFile.java:19)
```

So is there any other Class or way to write the file in /var/foo folder?

Comment: Have a super user run the program :p

Comment: If you don't have permission you don't have permission. If there was a way around it using a Java class, we'd be in a lot of trouble.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission Denied: File Creation in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131324/permission-denied-file-creation-in-java)

Comment: Run the program under sudo. Or have the program invoke something written in another languge which has setUID privilages and writes to that file for you. But in general, if you think you need root privileges for anything other than system maintenance, you're approaching the problem wrong.