# File created from within my Eclipse does not have read permissions

Tags: java, eclipse, file, permissions

A weird question:

I am running eclipse on windows and I am trying to open a file with a hard coded path:

```
String inputFile = "C:/temp/abc.txt";
File folder = new File(inputFile );
```

When I run this I get error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/temp/abc.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have local admin rights on this windows 10 machine. I have tried running Eclipse as a Administrator but it doesn't resolve the issue.

The only way I can get by is if I traverse to C:/temp/ in cygwin and do a chmod 777 * . Then my program is able to open the file okay.

The work around should be fine if I was just reading a simple file but I am also creating files from within my java project which it does successfully create but then when it comes to reading them it fails.

```
myFile.setReadable(true); // doesnt work either.
```

Is this some sort of windows permissions issue ? Could it be that cygwin has taken over some admin rights on the file system? I have tried stopping it but the issue persists. Or is this an eclipse setting?

Many Thanks,

-A

Comment: I guess it is a windows permission issue of the directory or parent directory in which the file is created. See second part of this answer: https://superuser.com/a/973359

Comment: yes it was a windows permissions issue :)

Answer (score 1):

It was a windows permissions issue.

Right click on the folder -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> Add -> Everyone.

I dont understand why I need to add every one if I am the local admin and I launched eclipse but frankly I dont care about the bizarre world of windows.

Thanks to all those who tried helping.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

check this.

[Permission Denied: File Creation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131324/permission-denied-file-creation-in-java)

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-the-file-permission-in-java/

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it didnt work. I have posted the solution I found.